# Using a Class 'Age' method in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble understanding how I calculate Age in my Class.

I understand the method on how it is calculated however I don't understand how I'm supposed to use it within my program.

I have an abstract Class called Person and there are properties for Person, Name, DOB etc...Then I have 2 classes, Dentist and Patient who inherit from Person. My program then needs to calculate the age from the DOB which I have created this method(Which was researched). Its the use of this method I'm finding difficult.

This is my Method:

```
public int AgeInYears(DateTime bday)
{
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        int age = now.Year - bday.Year;
        if (bday.AddYears(age) > now)
            age--;
        return age;
}
```

I also have a Surgery Class in which I have an arraylist for Dentist and Patient(I know Arraylists are bad - it was an instruction in the assignment from my lecturer). Then on my form I use these arraylists to populate Text boxes when either a dentist or patient is selected.

I will need to populate the txtAge box with the calculation from my method and the DOB in my Arraylist.

Could someone either point me in the right direction on how I do this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple.
According to gjttt1 answer You have to call Your method as described:

```
Int age = AgeInYears(dob)
```

'Int age' is variable declaration. This variable will store calculated age.

Now Your method step by step / line by line.

```
public int AgeInYears(DateTime bday)
```

It is declaration of method. It's name is 'AgeInYears', '(DateTime bday)' is input parameter, 'int' is returned type and 'public' is modifier. That all means that method AgeInYears will return Integer (System.Integer) if you give proper input parameter (bday = birthday) which have to be proper DateTime.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
```

This line is declaration of another variable, internal for method body. It will store value of method 'DateTime.Today' which is current date.

```
int age = now.Year - bday.Year;
```

Another Integer variable declaration with value. This calculation do simple thing: current year taken from variable 'now' minus year taken from input parameter 'bday'.

```
if (bday.AddYears(age) > now)
        age--;
```

This 'if' statement adds calculated age to input parameter 'bday' and comapres it to current DateTime (value of variable 'now'). If statement returns 'true', then calculated age is decreased by 1. This operation is performed because of some confusion in age calculation. Let me explain that:
if somebody was borned in 2000-12-29 and current date is 2016-04-19, so accroding to calculation his/her age is 16. But it's not true, because it is 15 and 16 will be achieved in 2016-12-29.

```
return age;
```

Returns calculated age value stored in variable 'age'.

EDIT:
I have just noticed part about TextBox and ArrayList.
If you need to populate age value in TextBox control you can achieve this with this basic instruction:

```
YourTextBoxName.Text = age.ToString();
```

'age' is variable declared on the beginning and it stores value of method 'AgeInYears'. 'Text' property says your TextBox control to display some text (string).
If you need to add 'age' to ArrayList, you have to use this instruction:

```
YourArrayListName.Add(age);
```

You can read more about ArrayList.Add() method here: [ArrayList.Add() on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for running through the method also, it makes sense now. I understand what I am meant to do. The trouble is calling the method. My Class is Public and the method is public and I have instantiated Person p = new Person(); in my form however it still states that the method does not exist. 

This is what I had done in the first instance but the method was not available so I assumed I was not calling the method correctly which seems clear now I am not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my English is not very good. Is everything clear to you now or you need some more explanations?

Comment: Yes it is very clear and I also know how to print to text boxes however it is calling the method which is causing me the issue. I have called the Person Class in my form however it wont let me use the method from the Person Class

Comment: private void lstNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Dentist d = Surgery.DentistByName(lstNames.SelectedItem.ToString());

            txtDID.Text = d.ID.ToString();
            txtDDOB.Text = d.DOB.ToShortDateString();
            txtSalary.Text = d.Wage.ToString();
            lstDaysWorked.Items.Clear();
            lstDaysWorked.Items.Add(d.Day1);
            lstDaysWorked.Items.Add(d.Day2);
            txtDGender.Text = d.Gender;
            txtDName.Text = d.Name;

            int age = AgeInYears(d.DOB);

Comment: Ive also instantiated Person p = new Person(); above this code

Comment: I think it's code from your form, but I have read your first comment one more time and I know how to help you (or I think I can help). So you have created instance of your Person class which is public and contains declaration of public method 'AgeInYears'. Your class instance is called 'p', right? So now you have to call your method like that: `int age = p.AgeInYears(d.DOB)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: That was it all along...That one letter stopped me from using the method..

Thank you for taking the time to help and more importantly explaining it all for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) You have to remember, that if you create object which is instance of a class ('p' in your case), you can access all public object/methods declared in it's body ONLY BY CREATED INSTANCE. This is extremely important in object oriented programing. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

To use the method you must call it and pass it a `DateTime` object. It will then return an `int` which is the age. For Example:

```
Int age = AgeInYears(dob)
```

where `dob` is the date of birth from one of your `Person`objects.

This is very simple stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry would you be able to explain this a little deeper I'm sorry as I am fresh to Programming.

Comment: I understand your code however the point of my question is how I implement this within my program. You have given me one line of code and not explained how I use it.

Comment: @Griff I think that was intentional. This site exists so that questions can be answered, not so that others can do your homework. You may find someone here who will spoon-feed an answer to you, but that's not going to help you in the long run.

Comment: @MichaelTodd is right. With very minimal research you can find out how to implement and use a function in your program.

Comment: Surely this site was created to help ?

I do not want any code to do this for me. Some Psuedo code on how it could be implemented would be helpful or a clearer explanation would help. The explanation was not useful